# checking if inputs are set in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using knockout.js and I want to check if two two text inputs have a value set. If they are, then do something.

The following works, but I want to know if there's "knockout" way to do it using custom bindings or some other way. I just want to learn more about knockout to be able to leverage its features in the future for more complex situations.

```
function DatesViewModel(startDate,endDate){

    var self = this;
    self.startDate = ko.observable("");
    self.endDate = ko.observable("");


    self.startDate.subscribe(function(newValue) {
         check_dates();
    });

    self.endDate.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        check_dates();
    });

    function check_dates(){
        if(self.startDate() !== "" && self.endDate() !== ""){
            alert('values set');
        }
    }

}
```

I tried to do what DoctorMick sugggest using a computed function, but either I'm misunderstanding the use of it, or it's just not working.

```
self.datesEntered = ko.computed(function() {
    if(self.startDate() !== "" && self.endDate() !== ""){
        return self.startDate() && self.endDate();
    }
});


self.datesEntered.subscribe(function() {
   alert(self.datesEntered);
});
```

The alert is triggered every time either of the dates are changed. Also, it's just returning a bunch of code.

Comment: You are almost there you just need to write, just need to write `self.datesEntered()` to get your computed's value so change your code to `alert(self.datesEntered());`

Comment: @nemesv that works, although the value returned is only the endDate, not both of the. Also, it is triggered even when only one date is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does depend on what you're actually trying to achieve but I'd use a computed based on the snippet above, so...

```
self.DatesEntered = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.startDate() && self.endDate();
});

self.datesEntered.subscribe(function(value) {
   if(value) {
       alert("Hurrah, both values entered");
   }
});
```

That way you can bind or subscribe to DatesEntered and do whatever you like once both have been keyed in.  As you can see, it simplifies the original code quite significantly.

Comment: I tried to make a computed function like you suggested, but I can' seem to get it to work. Can you please take a look at my original post, I updated it.

Comment: @user1852176 - I've edited my answer.  The computed will fire whenever either value is changed and will return a "truthy" (see: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) if both values are entered and a falsy value if both are not.  If you want to check that value you can add the value parameter in the subscription as per my updated answer.